# Getting error when i try to open eclipse in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am using Red Hat Linux. When i am trying to open eclipse in linux it is not opening and i am getting the following error in the .log file.

```
!SESSION 2011-04-13 10:35:08.073 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20060921-0945
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-04-13 10:35:13.007
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/98/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-3235.so: /usr/lib64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/98/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-3235.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1712)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:123)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:22)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(IDEApplication.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit JVM?

Comment: i downloaded 32bit eclipse and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the log message you are running eclipse 64-bit in a 64-bit machine but as you are suggesting on the comment you are running a 32-bit JVM. Either install 64-bit jdk/jre or install the 32-bit version of eclipse.